# Delete all backups of specific file/folder with tmutil

Tags: backup, time-machine, command-line, macos

I'm trying to delete all backups of specific items through the command line. I can accomplish this using the GUI through the following steps:

1. Enter Time Machine
2. Navigate to the file to be deleted
3. Right click (or click the gear icon in the finder) and choose
   "Delete all backups of ..."

How can I replicate this on the command line using `tmutil`? Especially, when using Backup Loupe to detect large files it'd be easier to use the Terminal (since I don't have to enter TimeMachine at all each time I want to delete a particular file and can navigate to it using the Finder, and then drop it onto Terminal for a command to delete it).

I was hoping I could use something like this:

```
sudo tmutil delete /path/to/file
```

however it gives me the error:

> "Invalid deletion target (error 22)"`

This works fine:

```
sudo tmutil delete /Volume/Backups.backupdb/<machinename>
```

and this too:

```
sudo tmutil delete /Volume/Backups.backupdb/<machinename>/<specificbackup>
```

According to `man tmutil` the `delete` command *should* also be able to delete specific items.  However, I've been out of luck so far. While there are numerous answers on this site (and elsewhere) to delete specific *backups* with `tmutil` and to delete specific backup *items* through the GUI (using the method described above) I was unable to find any non-GUI way to delete specific backup *items*.

Comment: @stephenwade I see you added a bounty to this question, thank you :)  Am I supposed to now accept an answer or are you supposed to give the bounty to someone?  I'm unclear how bounties on others' questions work.

Comment: You can accept (or not accept) whichever answer you like, without impact on the bounty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found this SU Q&A titled: [How can I delete Time Machine files using the commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/162690/how-can-i-delete-time-machine-files-using-the-commandline)
 which demonstrates a method for deleting specific files from the CLI. This answer highlighted a method that sounds like what you want:

> My backup disk is full. I have a very large file (many gigabytes) that
>   has been backed up for months. There is one physical copy of it, but
>   many snapshots with hard links to that copy. To actually get rid of
>   that file, I need to remove the hard link from every backup.

In that answer it was shown that one could use this method to delete a file:

```
$ cd /Volumes/WD\ 500G\ USB/Backups.backupdb/csm-laptop
$ ls -li */Macintosh\ HD/Users/csm/vm.img
...
2740350 -rw-r--r--@ 28 csm  staff  42949672960 Feb 17 16:12 2015-05-08-005636/Macintosh HD/Users/csm/vm.img
2740350 -rw-r--r--@ 28 csm  staff  42949672960 Feb 17 16:12 2015-05-08-015812/Macintosh HD/Users/csm/vm.img
2740350 -rw-r--r--@ 28 csm  staff  42949672960 Feb 17 16:12 2015-05-08-030036/Macintosh HD/Users/csm/vm.img
2740350 -rw-r--r--@ 28 csm  staff  42949672960 Feb 17 16:12 2015-05-08-041307/Macintosh HD/Users/csm/vm.img
2740350 -rw-r--r--@ 28 csm  staff  42949672960 Feb 17 16:12 Latest/Macintosh HD/Users/csm/vm.img
```

The method to delete the file uses a helper CLI tool included with Time Machine called `bypass`:

```
$ sudo bypass rm -f */Macintosh\ HD/Users/csm/vm.img
```

#### bypass's location

Since `bypass` is considered a helper script to Time Machine, it's location is not typically on your `$PATH`. Therefore you'll need to specify the full path to the executable. Additionally Apple has relocated it for different versions of macOS.

> ```
> $ sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/MacOS/bypass \
>     rm -rfv /Volumes/[disk]/Backups.backupdb/[path]
> ```
>
> In 10.8 Mountain Lion, bypass moved into 'Helpers':
>
> ```
> $ /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Helpers/bypass
> ```
>
> In 10.10 Yosemite, bypass moved here:
>
> ```
> $ /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass
> ```

#### References

- [How can I delete Time Machine files using the commandline](https://superuser.com/a/912432/20568)

Comment: This does indeed look like what I was after.   To clarify:  By "removing the hard link from every backup" you mean "from every snapshot", right?   And using the wildcard in the command  `sudo bypass rm -f */Macintosh\ HD\Users\csm\vm.img` ensures that all of this is accomplished in one go?

Comment: @Jan The `rm` runs after `cd /Volumes/DISK/Backups.backupdb/MACHINE` so the wildcard will expand to all the dated folders containing the image. I've fixed a `\\ ` - `/` typo in the answer though.

Comment: Yaaaaaasssss! I’ve been searching for this for years, will test on some less critical backups as I’m most interested in maintaining the integrity of the backup destination for ongoing backups. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180214/is-it-possible-to-use-tmutil-delete-or-another-command-to-prune-one-file-from

Comment: @bmike Please comment back and let me know what you find. I also have a few Macs that I need to do this on.

Comment: I will @stephenwade - it might be a week or two until I have free time to test this. It seems like `bypass` is exactly the scalpel I need for my tool. I’d like to wrap it in swift or python so it’s easier to use, but we’ll see if I revert to the shell

Comment: In case anyone has macOS 10.13 High Sierra, I wanted to mention `bypass` is located in the same place as it was in 10.10. I used it and it worked exactly as hoped.

Comment: Update: This won't work with an APFS Time Machine backup

Answer (score 6):

According to `man tmutil`, the `tmutil delete` command can be used to delete one or more *snapshots*, *machine directories*, or *backup stores*. The terms are defined at the beginning of the same man page:

- *snapshot*: A directory inside a machine directory that represents a single initial or incremental backup of one computer (e.g. `/Volumes/Chronoton/Backups.backupdb/thermopylae/2011-07-03-123456`)
- *machine directory*: A directory inside a backup store that contains all the backups for a particular computer (e.g. `/Volumes/Chronoton/Backups.backupdb/thermopylae`)
- *backup store*: The top-level "Backups.backupdb" directory at the root of a backup disk (e.g. `/Volumes/Chronoton/Backups.backupdb`)

So it seems as if it is unfortunately not possible to use `tmutil` to delete specific items within a snapshot.