# Has the Time Machine option to ""Delete all backups of" disappeared in Big Sur?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have a folder that gets filled with large files that I want Time Machine to remember while retaining the option of regularly forgetting these large files. For this and up until Catalina I would regularly enter Time machine, go to this folder and use the command `Delete all backups of...` (see for instance the screen capture of @Inder 's answer in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39287/how-can-i-manually-delete-old-backups-to-free-space-for-time-machine)). As of my recent upgrade to Big Sur I no longer see this contextual menu option.

Is it gone from MacOS for good? Is there an alternative that does not involve under-the-hood `sudo`-type terminal surgery?

Thanks!

PS. I had a look at [How to delete a file from Time Machine backups in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404564/how-to-delete-a-file-from-time-machine-backups-in-big-sur) but the issue, as I understand it, is different. I am looking for a way to delete *all* backups of a given folder, not a single backup (snapshot) of the *whole* system. Answers that call for `bypass` look a bit too scary for my taste.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks; I looked at the thread, however deleting a single TM backup of the whole system is not what I am looking for (deleting all backups of a given folder). The `bypass` route may be one way but as I said I am not confident enough to go there, especially with the risk of messing with a whole TM disk.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I'm puzzled and dismayed why Apple has chosen to do this, but I haven't had a chance to test Big Sur machine in my office. I rely on this functionality to remove successive FinalCut temp and render files from TM backups after projects are done, as well as pre-processed images/videos from SD card dumps, etc. I wonder if there is new functionality somewhere.

Comment: The linked article doesn't have an adequate answer. You can't delete "all backups of a single file/folder" with TMA. You can only delete whole snapshots. I use Chronosync (and exclude from TM) for any folders which I want backup of current version but for which I don't want history.  the `bypass` command disappeared some time ago and is irrelevant.

Comment: I have added an answer to the linked question which addresses your problem to expand a bit on my comment above.